# Button not anchoring to bottom of flexbox column

Tags: flexbox, anchor, multiple-columns

I have a three-column flexbox. Within each column I want a button to anchor itself in the very bottom left hand corner of the column. Following much research and trial and error I can't seem to achieve this - the button always moves up or down the column when viewed at different screen widths.  I've tried including the button within the text section, and also setting the button in it's own div within the column. It's important the columns remain an equal height on all screen widths, which has been achieved with the CSS below. Can anyone help with this problem?

```css
.flexbox {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.flexbox .col {
  flex: 1;
  margin: 10px;
}

.flexbox_colbutton {
  flex: 1;
 background: #fff;
 align-items: flex-end;
  display: flex;
 justify-content: left;
}

.flexbox .col:nth-child(1) {
  background: #fff;
  -webkit-order: 0;
  -ms-flex-order: 0;
  order: 0;
  box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2),0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.19);
}
.flexbox .col:nth-child(2) {
  background: #fff;
   -webkit-order: 1;
  -ms-flex-order: 1;
  order: 1;
  box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2),0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.19);
}
.flexbox .col:nth-child(3) {
  background: #fff;
  -webkit-order: 2;
  -ms-flex-order: 2;
  order: 2;
  box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2),0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.19);
}
.flexbox .col:nth-child(4) {
  background: #fff;
  -webkit-order: 3;
  -ms-flex-order: 3;
  order: 3;
  box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2),0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.19);
}


@media (max-width: 480px) {
   .flexbox col {
        max-width: 98%;
    }
 
 .flexbox {
     flex-direction: column;
   }
```

```html
<div class="flexbox">
    <div class="col">
    <br>
            <h5><center><strong>recent testimonial</strong></center></h5>
        <p class="text-justify w3-padding">..DREW performed very well from the outset.  When we had to value-engineer the project to bring it within budget they were extremely helpful with advice and assistance.  The Site Manager was courteous and informative, and throughout performance levels were excellent."<br><br>
      <i>Mark Holloway, Countryside Operations Manager, Bournemouth Borough Council<br>
      [Hengistbury Head Visitor Centre]</i></p>
      <br><br>
       <div class="flexbox_colbutton">
       <button class="w3-btn w3-red w3-medium" href="#">view project</button>
      </div>
      </div>
      
    
    
      <div class="col">
          <br>
            <h5><center><strong>WHY OUR CLIENTS CHOOSE DREW</strong></center></h5>
           <p class="text-justify text-left w3-padding">
          &#10004; our clients are our first priority <br>&#10004; triple badge ISO accreditation <br>&#10004; highly experienced Director-led project teams<br>
      &#10004; collaborative working approach to project delivery<br>
      &#10004; extensive in-house technical expertise <br>&#10004; financially stable and long-established Company <br>
      &#10004; excellent record on health, safety and the environment</p><br>
      <br>
      <div class="flexbox_colbutton">
       <button class="w3-btn w3-red w3-medium" href="#">read more</button>
      </div>
      </div>
        
    
    <div class="col">
    
    <br>
            
            <h5><center><strong>recent testimonial</strong></center></h5>
        <p class="text-justify w3-padding">"..The scheme was delivered to budget and, although a challenging design, is of the highest quality. During construction DREW worked  to ensure it responded with practical solutions to some challenging requirements .. I would certainly recommend them for future projects."<br><br>
      <i>David Morris, Sweett (UK)<br>[St George's Primary School]</i></p><br> 
      <br><br>
    <div class="flexbox_colbutton">
       <button class="w3-btn w3-red w3-medium" href="#">view project</button>
      </div>
      </div>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I’d suggest to use flexbox for the columns, too:

```
.flexbox .col {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
```

Now we can make the `<p>` tags take all the remaining space, effectively pushing the button to the bottom of the columns.

```
.col p {
    flex: 1;
}
```

Note: If you add other content as a direct child of `.col` (like a `<ul>`), you have to set `flex: 1` for it, too. The button must *not* have a flex-grow set, so remove the line `flex: 1;` from `.flexbox_colbutton`.

You can find the whole, edited sample below. In my tests, the button always was at the bottom edge and the page behaved like I suppose it should.

```css
.flexbox {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;     
}
  
  
.flexbox .col {
  flex: 1;
  margin: 10px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.col p {
  flex: 1;
}

.flexbox_colbutton {
  background: #fff;
  display: flex;
}

.flexbox .col:nth-child(1) {
  background: #fff;
  -webkit-order: 0;
  -ms-flex-order: 0;
  order: 0;
  box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2),0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.19);
}
.flexbox .col:nth-child(2) {
  background: #fff;
   -webkit-order: 1;
  -ms-flex-order: 1;
  order: 1;
  box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2),0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.19);
}
.flexbox .col:nth-child(3) {
  background: #fff;
  -webkit-order: 2;
  -ms-flex-order: 2;
  order: 2;
  box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2),0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.19);
}

.flexbox .col:nth-child(4) {
  background: #fff;
  -webkit-order: 3;
  -ms-flex-order: 3;
  order: 3;
  box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2),0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.19);
}


@media (max-width: 480px) {
   .flexbox col {
        max-width: 98%;
    }
 
 .flexbox {
     flex-direction: column;
   }
```

```html
    <div class="flexbox">
    <div class="col">
    <br>
            <h5><center><strong>recent testimonial</strong></center></h5>
        <p class="text-justify w3-padding">..DREW performed very well from the outset.  When we had to value-engineer the project to bring it within budget they were extremely helpful with advice and assistance.  The Site Manager was courteous and informative, and throughout performance levels were excellent."<br><br>
      <i>Mark Holloway, Countryside Operations Manager, Bournemouth Borough Council<br>
      [Hengistbury Head Visitor Centre]</i></p>
      <br><br>
       <div class="flexbox_colbutton">
       <button class="w3-btn w3-red w3-medium" href="#">view project</button>
      </div>
      </div>
      
    
    
      <div class="col">
          <br>
            <h5><center><strong>WHY OUR CLIENTS CHOOSE DREW</strong></center></h5>
           <p class="text-justify text-left w3-padding">
          &#10004; our clients are our first priority <br>&#10004; triple badge ISO accreditation <br>&#10004; highly experienced Director-led project teams<br>
      &#10004; collaborative working approach to project delivery<br>
      &#10004; extensive in-house technical expertise <br>&#10004; financially stable and long-established Company <br>
      &#10004; excellent record on health, safety and the environment</p><br>
      <br>
      <div class="flexbox_colbutton">
       <button class="w3-btn w3-red w3-medium" href="#">read more</button>
      </div>
      </div>
        
    
    <div class="col">
    
    <br>
            
            <h5><center><strong>recent testimonial</strong></center></h5>
        <p class="text-justify w3-padding">"..The scheme was delivered to budget and, although a challenging design, is of the highest quality. During construction DREW worked  to ensure it responded with practical solutions to some challenging requirements .. I would certainly recommend them for future projects."<br><br>
      <i>David Morris, Sweett (UK)<br>[St George's Primary School]</i></p><br> 
      <br><br>
    <div class="flexbox_colbutton">
       <button class="w3-btn w3-red w3-medium" href="#">view project</button>
      </div>
      </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: Hi Joshua - Thank you. This worked well in achieving my main goal. Although the button is now full width of the column which wasn't what I intended, I think it looks better, so will go with that!  Unfortunately,  it meant that text in the columns seems to have been pushed down, and this is very noticeable on medium screens, although not quite so much on large or small devices. Are you able to advise how I might correct this so that the text is correctly aligned to the top?  Thank you so much for your help so far.

Comment: @JanD I have updated my answer to better fit your needs.

Comment: „Although the button is now full width“: This is odd. As you can see when running the code snippet on my answer, the button is not full width.

Comment: Some tips for your code: 1. Don’t use `<center>`, set `text-align: center` in the CSS. 2. Don’t use `<br>`s for spacing, set `padding` or `margin` in the CSS. 3. You *don’t* have to use `order` if the elements are already in the correct order! So you can remove all your `nth-child(x)`s and just make one rule for all `.flexbox .col`s.